# how to set the pyversions icon on my github readme?

Tags: python, travis-ci, pypi, shields.io

I'm trying to set my pyversion icon to my github README, similar to this:

[image: expected badge]

I've been trying to reverse engineer the setup from the [coveralls-python project](https://github.com/coveralls-clients/coveralls-python).

My .travis.yaml file looks like this:

```
language: python
python:
  - "2.7"
  - "3.3"
  - "3.4"
  - "3.5"
  - "3.6"
install: 
  - pip install tox-travis
  - pip install python-coveralls

script:
  - tox
  - coverage run --source ibm_analytics_engine -m ibm_analytics_engine.iae
  - coverage report -m

after_success:
  - coveralls
```

And my README has:

```
[![Pyversions](https://img.shields.io/pypi/pyversions/ibm-analytics-engine-python.svg?style=flat-square)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ibm-analytics-engine-python)
```

However, my output looks like this:

[image: actual badge]

Where does the pyversions information get taken from?  Is it from the pypi page?  If not, how do I get shields.io to reflect the versions of python my library supports?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, the python versions is read from PyPi.

I just needed to add this to my setup.py trove classifiers:

```
Programming Language :: Python
Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6
Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7
Programming Language :: Python :: 3.3
Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4
Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5
```